# Add duration to an NSDate

Tags: ios, datetime, ios6, nsdate

How do I add duration to the datetime. For example 30 minutes.

```
 NSString *str = @"31-06-2013 11:45 pm";

 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a"];
 NSDate *startTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString: str];
 NSDate *endTime = [startTime dateByAddingTimeInterval:60 * 30];
```

The Output display **31-06-2013 11:45 pm** but the correct should be **01-06-2013 12:15 am**

Comment: This is a duplicate of many, many questions, so many I can't find a representative one. Bottom line - you're creating a date from a string for a time, but not providing a time zone for it - typically it will default to UTC. Then, you are probably printing `endTime` with `NSLog` or through `po` in the debugger - this will print the time in UTC. So, you need to 1) provide your time zone to the date formatter before calling `dateFromString:` and 2) create another date formatter, also with your time zone, to get the output you actually need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As many have pointed out this is a duplicate question albeit with a different component of the date. Here is a good way to do it to adjust the minute component of a date.

```
    NSCalendar*       calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
    NSDateComponents *c = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
    c.minute = 30;
    NSDate* endTime = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:c toDate:startTime options:0];
    NSString* formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:endTime];
```

Comment: Thanks. I try use method above it show 2000-01-01 05:49:00 +0000 and want to display dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a format.

Comment: see my edit above. You can then format the date using NSDateFormatter the same way you formatted the startTime but using stringFromDate instead of dateFromString.

Comment: Thanks kushyar.It realy workks.